# Make rows sort together in excel without having value

Tags: excel, sorting, office365

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets.

Column A of Sheet 1 and 2 are the exact same data. When I sort the first sheets data, Sheet 2 Column A is automatically sorted because it is referenced. (='Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$100).

But when I sort the above, Column B's cells in Sheet 2 don't follow the row of data. Now the data gets messed up because B2 in Sheet 2 did not move with the original A2 data that is referencing the first sheet.

Is there a way to keep the data together?

Below are images of sample data:

Sheet 1
[image: Sheet 1]
Sheet 2
[image: Sheet 2]

Now when I sort sheet 1 from Z-A: 
Sheet 1 Sorted:
[image: Sheet 1 Z-A]
Sheet 2's sorted data (Not matching) 
[image: Sheet 2 Z-A]

I want the phone number and contact name in sheet 2 to follow Alafia Village. Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: Only Column 1's data in sheet 2 is mirroring the first sheets. The other columns are new data that are entered by user and can change. I want to make the entered data stay with the row of the corresponding nursing home as when it was entered.

Comment: Possibly doable with VBA, but to be honest it seems like bad design, just waiting for data quality issues to occur.

Comment: It seemed like a bad design to me as well, to be honest. There is already another phone number etc attached to the first sheet. The second sheet is used for notes and NEW phone numbers found. I might just keep to one sheet

Comment: Yeah that's the way I'd go, if that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I don't agree that this is fundamentally bad design. If your two sheets were two tables in a database and you wanted to join them on 'something' so that the name was taken from the first table and the other details from the second table, that would be fine - much better than duplicating the names in the second table, which would be bad design. The only is issue is that the 'something' here is the row number and as soon as the order in sheet 1 changes, the row number doesn't work any more.

The answer would be to have a key in sheet 1 and look up the key in sheet 2. If this key were in column C (say) in both sheets, you would have an index/match in column A of sheet 2 like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C2,Sheet1!C:C,0))
```

In practice, you might also want to look at Power Query.